# Handle one query parameter specifically

Tags: regex, apache, redirect, mod-rewrite, parameters

I need to handle one query parameter specifically.
The url can look like the following:

```
https://example.com/?app=egov&map=1337
https://example.com/?app=egov&map=1337&showoptions=true
https://example.com/?app=egov&map=1337&showoptions=true&anotherparam=helloWorld
```

The redirect should point to

```
https://example.com/contextName/resources/apps/egov/index.html?map=1337
https://example.com/contextName/resources/apps/egov/index.html?map=1337&showoptions=true
https://example.com/contextName/resources/apps/egov/index.html?map=1337&anotherparam=helloWorld
```

As you can see, the `app`-Parameter needs to be used as an URL-part; the others need to be used like traditional query-params.
I've figured out, how to implement the first part, where `https://example.com/?app=egov` points to `https://example.com/contextName/resources/apps/egov/index.html` using the following

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^app\=(.+)
RewriteRule ^/$ "/contextName/resources/apps/%1/index.html" [R,L,QSA]
```

but I'm struggeling how to realize the correct handling of the other params.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All these combination of query string can be handled by a single rule loke this:

```sh
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^app=([\w-]+)(?:&(.*))?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ contextName/resources/apps/%1/index.html?%2 [L]
```

`RewriteCond` matches `app` query parameter and captures it in `%1` while rest of the query string after `&` is captured in `%2`.

Answer (score 2):

With your shown samples, please try following htaccess Rules file. Please make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
####Apache documentation link https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/rewrite/remapping.html for more info.
##Internal rewrite rule for URL https://example.com/?app=egov&map=1337
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^app=([^&]*)&map=(\d+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ contextName/resources/apps/%1/index.html?map=%2 [L]

##Internal rewrite rule for URL https://example.com/?app=egov&map=1337&showoptions=true
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^app=([^&]*)&map=(\d+)&showoptions=(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$  contextName/resources/apps/%1/index.html?map=%2&showoptions=%3 [L]

##Internal rewrite rule for https://example.com/?app=egov&map=1337&showoptions=true&anotherparam=helloWorl
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^app=([^&]*)&map=(\d+)&showoptions=([^&]*)&anotherparam=(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$  contextName/resources/apps/%1/index.html?map=%2&anotherparam=%4 [L]
```

All of your URLs uri part is NULL, so rules are written based on that.